Approximation of an irrational number by sequence of rational numbers, but with assumption on denominators.
Let $\lbrace a_{n}\rbrace $ be a sequence of natural numbers (strongly increases) and $r\in (0,1)$ be an irrational number.
Is it possible to find a sequence $\lbrace b_{n}\rbrace$ such that $\mathrm{gcd}(a_{n},b_{n})=1$ and $\frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}} \to r$?
For example i know that for each $a_{n}$ i can consider a Farey sequence $F_{a_{n}}$ and pick the element $\frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}} \in F_{a_{n}}$ in such a way that it is the largest number of this form in $F_{a_{n}}$ less than $r$.
How can i prove that $|\frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}-r|\to 0$?

By using a suitable $b_n$ , we can make the difference $\frac{1}{a_n}$ or less (Dirichlet's approximation theorem) and this , per assumption , tends to $0$.

@Peter i dont see that, because if we have fixed $a_{n}$, then probably we can't use Dirichlet's approximation theorem. Am i wrong? How can we have a guarantee that such $b_{n}$ exists?

For a given $a_n$ and your $b_n$, the distance $|b_n/a_n-r|\leq|b_n-b_{n+1}|/a_n\leq j(a_n)/a_n$, where $j$ is the Jacobsthal function. Using the asymptotic in the link, that $j(n)=O(log^2(n))$, we have that $j(a_n)/a_n\to0$.

The bound on the Jacobsthal function, by H. Iwaniec, can be found here.

@ameg can u explain this first inequality? what is $b_{n+1}$? Because it looks like it should be the number that we choose for $a_{n+1}$? Thanks in advance!

I shouldn't have called them $b_{n+1}$. Let me rephrase. Let $b_n$ be your $b_n$ and $c_n$ be the next number that is relatively prime to $a_n$, larger than $b_n$. Then $|b_n/a_n-r|\leq|b_n/a_n-c_n/a_n|=|b_n-c_n|/a_n\leq j(a_n)/a_n$. The last inequality is because the Jacobsthal's function measures the largest gap between consecutive number relatively prime and smaller than the input.

If

$r\in (0,1)$,
$a_n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ is strictly increasing,
$1=d_1<d_2<...<d_{\phi(a_n)}<a_n$ be integers relatively prime to $a_n$,
$b_n$ is the largest $d_k$ with $b_n/a_n\leq r$
$c_n$ is the smallest $d_k$ with $r\leq c_n/a_n$

Then $\left|\frac{b_n}{a_n}-r\right|\leq \left|\frac{b_n}{a_n}-\frac{c_n}{a_n}\right|\leq \frac{j(a_n)}{a_n}$
where $j$ is the Jacobsthal's function, which bounds the largest distance between consecutive $d_k$.
H. Iwaniec proved that
$j(n)=O(\log^2(n))$
Therefore, $\frac{j(a_n)}{a_n}\to0$

I read that Iwaniec proved that j(n)=O((nlog(n))^2)=O(n^2log^2(n)). How do u find this bound O(log^2(n))?

@ax1507 No, that looks like the bound for $j(p_1p_2...p_n)$, the value for the product of the first primes. The thing is that he works with this one, since the bound for all $n$ reduces to that for the primorial numbers.

@ax1507 See here an overview of the proof.
